# Placing HTML within directive tags

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

So far, I've been adding HTML to a directive via template/templateURL, but recently wanted to be able to vary the template of a directive based on what page its called on. I looked online and saw mention of putting HTML directly in the directive tags (in the main HTML file), and I've done that, but any of the code I put in that HTML works off the root scope rather than the directive scope, when someone I spoke to said that it should work off the directive scope.

Is there any way to bind the HTML in directive tags not imported from templates to the directive scope they're in? Or do I have to separate it to a different file and import via templates?

Basically, can I do something like this:

```
<setup-itemized>
    <input type="text" ng-model="si.value">
</setup-itemized>
```

Where `si.value` is defined and setup in the `setupItemized` directive rather than in the root scope?

http://plnkr.co/XCUzurOmV8yDyKhWnhfi

Comment: Take a look at transclusion. Also seems like the plunker is not related to what you are asking or is it?.

Comment: Plunker decided not to save my changes; I've fixed that. And given that transclusion is being phased out of Angular, I'd prefer not to use it. I've already removed references to it on my site. Regardless, its not quite what I want. The question is if I can get non-template, inline HTML to work with a directive or if I have to go with templates.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify. I've been told that transclusion is being removed, and that I shouldn't be using it.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve that, take this example:

http://jsbin.com/sasexum/edit?html,js,console,output

index.html

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">
  <setup-itemized value="ctrl.value">
    <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.value">
  </setup-itemized>
</div>
```

main-controller.js:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function() {
    vm = this;
    console.log('Loading MainCtrl and assign 1 to variable value');
    vm.value = 1;
})
```

setup-itemized.js:

```
.directive('setupItemized', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {},
        bindToController: {
          value: '='
        },
        controller: function($scope) {
            vm = this;
            console.log('Loading Directive Controller and assign 10 to variable value');
            vm.value = 10;

            $scope.$watch('si.value', function(newVal) {
              console.log('New value for variable!');
            });
        },
        controllerAs: 'si',
        template: '<h1>Setup Itemized</h1>' +
                '<p>This is yuor custom directive with transclude!</p>' +
                '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>'
    };
});
```

As you can see you need to declare your "value" variable in the parent controller and pass it through directive and input. In this way, you have a two way binding with that variable and every change is reflected in both controller and directive.